# How do I navigate to my Google Drive for Work?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

How do you intuitively navigate to your admin panel for your Google Drive for Work account?

So far the only way I have found to do so is to google "Admin Console Google" and it brings up a support article.

I then load the support article, via clicking it from the Google search results.

Upon the loading of this page, I click the blue button on the support article that takes me to my admin console.

Other than bookmarking or manually typing the URL, this is the only way I see to navigate to it.

If I just go to Google Drive, while signed into the account, it only takes me to Google Drive, with no way to access the admin console.

Very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an account to confirm, but try clicking on the google square buttons top right of the page after you log in. Is there a way there to add the Admin console?

Looking at their help page, it looks like there should be. "Find your own apps in the grid" on the link https://support.google.com/a/answer/182076?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

To access the Google Apps Administrator Console, navigate to http://admin.google.com and sign in with an administrator account.